# How to run a go-gin server on a specific IP address

Tags: go

I am running a gin server using

```
r.RunTLS(":8080" , "domain.crt", "domain.key")
```

This starts the server with localhost as host-name. I can access my APIs using localhost host-name. How can I change this behavior to point to IP address instead of localhost?

Comment: Have you tried `r.RunTLS("1.2.3.4:8080", "domain.crt", "domain.key"))`? (obviously replace `1.2.3.4` with the intended IP)

Comment: Yes this does not work

Comment: And what error do you get? [`Engine.RunTLS()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Engine.RunTLS) returns an error, please be kind to check and post it.

Comment: I do not get any error. It says server `[GIN-debug] Listening and serving HTTPS on 1.1.1.1:9000` but when I try to access the rest api it does not work. As soon as I remove 1.1.1.1 it works on localhost.

Comment: What did you do when you tried access it ? What happened ? (Copy/paste any command you ran) You naturally need to specify an IP that is configured on the machine, and you need to connect to that specific IP address, not localhost

Comment: You cannot specify an IP that the PC cannot use. Your computer already has an IP address assigned by the network it is using, the `RunTLS` method tells your API where to listen, it does not assign your computer an IP address, that's handled by the OS. You will need to provide more information to help, especially what you are trying to accomplish. If you want to access the application using your computers IP you will need to find out what that is first and combine that with the port, ie. `192.168.1.13:8080`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
   r := gin.Default()
   r.Run("IP:PORT")
```

(change IP and PORT to sample as you want)